# Var not being changed with jQuery replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove text from the stored var when a div is clicked. My code looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var allids = '';

  $("#artistselect").change(function() {

  var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
  allids.push($(this).children(":selected").attr("value"));

  selectid = "#" + id; 
  echoid = "#artistecho" + id; 

  $(echoid).show(300); 
  $(selectid).hide(0);
  $("input[name=artistslist]").val(allids.join(", "));

  alert(allids);

  });

    $(".remove").click(function() {

    var removeid = $(this).attr("value");

    var allids = allids.replace(removeid, '');

     $('input[name=artistslist]').val(function(index, value) {
       return value.replace(removeid, '');
    });



    alert(allids);
    });
  });
```

This function is working fine:

```
$("#artistselect").change(function() {
```

Im having problems with this function:

```
$(".remove").click(function() {
```

It is not modifying the var allids, nor is it giving me alert(allids);

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have `allids` array declared anywhere.

Comment: `allids.replace(removeid, '')` is maybe wrong? `allids` is an array?

Comment: Make sure you close your document ready function with `});`.

Comment: Along with `replace()` not being a function for an array, by using `var allids` within the callback you have made it a local scoped variable and is no longer the outer scope allids

Comment: I forgot to include that allids was in fact declared and is not an array.

Comment: remove var for allids and check

Answer (score 0):

allids must be array and its should not be again decaled with var in $(".remove").click(function() {

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

     var allids = [];

      $("#artistselect").change(function() {

      var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
      allids.push($(this).children(":selected").attr("value"));

      selectid = "#" + id; 
      echoid = "#artistecho" + id; 

      $(echoid).show(300); 
      $(selectid).hide(0);
      $("input[name=artistslist]").val(allids.join(", "));

      alert(allids);

      });

        $(".remove").click(function() {

        var removeid = $(this).attr("value");

        allids = allids.replace(removeid, '');

         $('input[name=artistslist]').val(function(index, value) {
           return value.replace(removeid, '');
        });



        alert(newids);
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define your **allids** as a **array** and **selectid** & **echoid** as **variable**. Here is code.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

      var allids = [];

      $("#artistselect").change(function() {

      var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
      allids.push($(this).children(":selected").attr("value"));

      var selectid = "#" + id; 
      var echoid = "#artistecho" + id; 

      $(echoid).show(300); 
      $(selectid).hide(0);
      $("input[name=artistslist]").val(allids.join(", "));

      alert(allids);

      });

        $(".remove").click(function() {

        var removeid = $(this).attr("value");

        allids = allids.replace(removeid, '');

         $('input[name=artistslist]').val(function(index, value) {
           return value.replace(removeid, '');
        });



        alert(newids);
        });
      })
```

Comment: even with allids declared as an array and selectid and echoid as vars , it is not changing. it is now however giving me the alert(allids);